# sum of all actual values of a totient function for given n

Tags: math, greatest-common-divisor

How can i efficiently find the sum of all actual values of a totient function for given n.
for eg. tot(10) are 1,3,7,9 => 1+3+7+9 = 20.
I tried the brute force approach below

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(gcd(i,n)==1)sum += i;
}
print(sum)
```

which is O(nxlog(n)).
where log(n) is for gcd computation at each step.
Constraints : 1<=n<=10^6. 
If there exist any better solution?

Comment: If n is large enough then a variant of the [wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) technique should save substantial time.

Comment: Try computing the first few elements of the sequence for n = 1, 2, 3, ... and then look at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences to see what's known about that sequence. It seems likely that someone has studied it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print out the first values of the function, you get:

1, 1, 3, 4, 10, 6, 21, 16, 27, 20, 55, 24, 78, 42, 60, 64, 136, ...

Looking up the function in [oeis](https://oeis.org), you find [A023896](https://oeis.org/A023896): "Sum of totatives of n, i.e., sum of integers up to n and coprime to n". And there we get a formula:
`n*phi(n)/2` except for `n=1`. Here`phi` is Euler's [totient function](https://oeis.org/A000010), for which Euler himself indicated a fast calculation: `n * Product_{distinct primes p dividing n} (1 - 1/p)`.

Putting everything together into some pure Python functions:

```py
import math

def prime_factors(n):
    if n == 1:
        return []
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return [2] + prime_factors(n//2)
    if n % 3 == 0:
        return [3] + prime_factors(n//3)
    if n % 5 == 0:
        return [5] + prime_factors(n//5)
    for i in range(6, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 6):
        if n % (i + 1) == 0:
            return [i + 1] + prime_factors(n // (i + 1))
        if n % (i + 5) == 0:
            return [i + 5] + prime_factors(n // (i + 5))
    return [n]

def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return gcd(b, a % b)

def totative_sum(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if gcd(n, i) == 1:
            s += i
    return s

def phi(n):
    prod = n
    for i in set(prime_factors(n)): # convert to a set, because we don't want duplicates
        # prod = prod * (1 - 1 / i)
        prod = prod * (i - 1) // i  # rewrite the formula to only work with integers
    return int(prod)

def fast_totative_sum(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * phi(n) // 2

print([totative_sum(n) for n in range(1, 31)])
print([fast_totative_sum(n) for n in range(1, 31)])

n = 12345678
print(fast_totative_sum(n))
print(totative_sum(n))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 3, 4, 10, 6, 21, 16, 27, 20, 55, 24, 78, 42, 60, 64, 136, 54, 171, 80, 126, 110, 253, 96, 250, 156, 243, 168, 406, 120]
24860442405888
```

Note that here the prime factorization only steps through possible factors of 6k+1 and 6k+5. This could be optimized even more, stepping modulo 30 where only 8 factors need to be tested and 22 can be skipped. (And so on, modulo 210=2*3*5*7 etc.).

If you need to calculate the prime factors for a lot of numbers, you could build a sieve of Eratosthenes and save the result in a list. That way you only need to step through real primes to find the prime factors.